# Find $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{n!}$ without Stirling's approximation.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Okay I've seen many posts as this one, but in every post it uses Stirling(I can't use it because I've never learnt it), or weird equalities with logs (I also never learnt this) or other methods I'm not allowed to use in my exam.

I have to prove that $\lim n!^{(1/n)}$ = $\infty$, only by using D'Alembert, $n^{th}$ root test, Stolz, squeeze theorem or by playing with inequalities etc

What I thought is that I could prove that $\lim \frac{1}{n!^{(1/n)}} = 0$ (again only using those basic theorems) and that would mean that $\lim n!^{(1/n)} = \infty$ but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Please don't mark as duplicate! I need an answer and I haven't found any post with an answer I can use!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can't really use any of the answers in that post, anyways, already got an answer here I'm allowed to use.

Comment: @puradrogasincortar What's in the first answer to that post that you can't use?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't understand how the first inequality is achieved. I could memorize it but I prefer searching for an answer I can actually understand (already found it, np)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}
$$
The ratio test proves that the series converges. Therefore,
with $a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$, we have
$$
\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}
= \lim \sqrt[n]{a_{n}}
= \lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
= \lim \frac{1}{n+1} = 0
$$
and so
$$
\lim \sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that since $n!\ge(n/2)^{n/2}$, we have

$$\sqrt[n]{n!}\ge \sqrt{n/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(\sqrt[n]{n!}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\ln 1 + \ln 2 + \cdots + \ln n\right) \stackrel{\text{Cesàro}}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(n+1) = +\infty$$

Now exponentiate both sides and use the fact that exponentiation is continuous (or strictly increasing).

Comment: What is $\stackrel{\text{Stolz}}{=}$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\frac{1+2+3+...+n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{n!}$$ and $$1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: $$\therefore (n + 1)^n \geqslant 2^n\times n!$$

Comment: This is not useful to prove that the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: As Crostul states: so, you get an **upperbound** on $n!$? That's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$n! \ge (\frac{n}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}} \implies (n!)^{1/n} \ge \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$

Comment: I beat you by 21 seconds.

Comment: I've seen those in other post. I can't use that inequalities, I know I'm allowed to but I don't understand how they're achieved, so I prefer @lhf answer.

Comment: @puradrogasincortar Maybe try to understand the inequality -- you'll see, it's not too hard. $n!$ is the product of $n$ terms, all at least 1: $n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdots (n/2+1)\cdots 2\cdot 1$. So $n!$ is greater than or equal to the product of the first $n/2$ of these terms: $$n! \geq n\cdot(n-1)\cdots (n/2+1)$$ Now, these $n/2$ terms are all greater than $n/2$, so $$n! \geq (n/2)\cdot(n/2)\cdots (n/2) = (n/2)^{n/2}$$

Comment: @ClementC. I already understood it, thanks for the deep explanation.